# AngularJS Контроллер возвращает [object Object]

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-init="loadImage('/image/load/', event.listfile)"></div>
```

В `event.listfile` :

```
[
{id: 797, filename: "image1.jpg"},
{id: 800, filename: "image12.jpg"},
{id: 798, filename: "image47.jpg"}
]
```

Контроллер:

```
   $scope.loadImage = function(path, name) {
               $scope.image = [];
               name.forEach(function (element, index) {
                   $scope.image.push({"filename": path +name[index]});
               });
               console.log('image: ', $scope.image);
           }
```

Почему контроллер возвращает в консоль вместо имен файлов `[object Object]`:

```
/image/load/[object Object]
/image/load/[object Object]
/image/load/[object Object]
```

Comment: какая связь между предоставленным кодом и `/image/load/[object Object]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, `name[index]` - эквивалентно `element` в твоем коде.

Во-вторых, результат закономерный, так как элемент массива `name` является объектом. Если тебе нужно поле этого объекта, поле и надо выбирать.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
$scope.image.push({"filename": path + element.filename});
```

Кроме того, данную реализацию  [функции `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) можно заменить на вызов нативной функции:

```
$scope.loadImage = function(path, name) {
    $scope.image = name.map(el=>({"filename": path +el.filename}));
    console.log('image: ', $scope.image);
}
```

Comment: Имена стали отображаться. Спасибо!